# What is the Microsoft Graph API for adding a row to Excel present in another drive?

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-api

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tablerowcollection-add

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/table-post-rows

These documents don't mention how to add row in Excel file present in another drive.

Although I have got the below API which works but it's not mentioned anywhere in documentation.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0
 /sites/{siteId}
 /drives/{driveId}
 /items/{itemId}
 /workbook/tables/Status/rows/add
```

I need to get the actual documentation for the API to update Excel present in another drive for which I have the driveId.